# why does async function behaves differently when using with addEventListener and calling it manually

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I was trying to understand async and await keywords. I wrote a simple HTML file along with a JS file to demonstrate it.

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("Promise1 resolved");
  }, 10000);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("Promise2 resolved");
  }, 5000)
})

async function handlePromises() {
  const result1 = await promise1;
  console.log(result1);
  const result2 = await promise2;
  console.log(result2);
}

handlePromises();

// const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
// myButton.addEventListener("click", handlePromises);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="myButton">Click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

The console shows both

```
Promise1 resolved
Promised2 resolved
```

10 seconds after reloading the page(which is expected) But if I uncomment the last 2 lines and comment `handlePromises()` function and clicked the button, the console shows both

```
Promise1 resolved
Promise2 resolved
```

after 5 seconds. I thought it would behave the same way as the first case.

And If I click the button once more without reloading the page, the console prints

```
Promise1 resolved
Promise2 resolved
```

instantly.

Why is the same function behaving differently in different sceneraios.

Comment: `await` doesn't "start" a promise. When you create the promises the timer is already running. You're just executing the async function at different times, therefore potentially waiting less for the promises because some time has already ticked.

Answer (score 2):

The timers start as soon as you initialize each Promise. In the button click scenario, the timers are already running by the time you can interact with the page and click the button. And the second time you click the button, the timers have expired and each Promise is already resolved.